# How to speed up this loop using multiprocessing (pool.map)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have this loop I've written to find all the combinations of some set of data that I have. When iteration_depth = 3, it takes ~13 minutes to run. My laptop has 2 cores though, so I want to speed it up with `multiprocessing`, but since I don't really know what I'm doing, the syntax/arguments are tripping me up.

```
import multiprocessing

def FindAllAffordableLineups():
    all_rosters = []
    roster = [None]*8

    for n in range(int(iteration_depth)):
        for catcher in catcher_pool[0:n]:
            roster = [None]*8
            roster[0] = catcher[0]
            for first_baseman in first_pool[0:n]:
                roster[1] = first_baseman[0]
                for second_baseman in second_pool[0:n]:
                    roster[2] = second_baseman[0]
                    for third_baseman in third_pool[0:n]:
                        roster[3] = third_baseman[0]
                        for shortstop in short_pool[0:n]:
                            roster[4] = shortstop[0]
                            for outfielders in it.combinations(of_pool, 3):
                                roster[5:8] = outfielders[0][0], outfielders[1][0], outfielders[2][0]
                                salaryList = []
                                for player1 in roster:
                                    for player2 in player_pool:
                                        if player1 == player2[0]:
                                            salaryList.append(int(player2[3]))
                                if sum(salaryList) <= remaining_salary:
                                    if len(roster) == len(set(roster)):
                                        all_rosters.append(roster[:])
                                        if len(all_rosters) < 50:
                                            print('Number of possible rosters found: ',len(all_rosters))
                                        if len(all_rosters) == 50:
                                            print("Fifty affordable rosters were found. We're not displaying every time we find another one. That would slow us down a lot.")          
                                        salaryList = []
                                if len(all_rosters) > 10**6:
                                    writeRosters = open(os.path.join('Affordable Rosters.csv'), 'w', newline = '')
                                    csvWriter = csv.writer(writeRosters)
                                    for row in all_rosters:
                                        csvWriter.writerow(row)
                                    writeRosters.close()
                                    all_rosters = []
        writeRosters = open(os.path.join('Affordable Rosters.csv'), 'w', newline = '')
        csvWriter = csv.writer(writeRosters)
        for row in all_rosters:
            csvWriter.writerow(row)
        writeRosters.close()

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
r = pool.map(FindAllAffordableLineups())
```

This gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Multiprocessing\11 - Find Optimal Lineup.py", line 133, in <module>
    r = pool.map(FindAllAffordableLineups())
TypeError: map() missing 1 required positional argument: 'iterable'
```

In most of the examples I've looked at, the defined function has some argument that needs to be executed inside of the function, and that's the iterable in `map.pool` command, but my function doesn't require this. How do I fix this?

Comment: This is your second question related to this project you're working on, which is fine, but I don't think you've really explained _what you're trying to do_ well. I have a feeling that a good solution to your problem is simpler than you're making it out to be, but we need a good, clear explanation. I realize this doesn't directly answer this question; I'm just trying to help with the _real_ problem.

Comment: r = pool.map(FindAllAffordableLineups()) so mean r = pool.map(function,iterable)   https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @Cyphase it's more for me to learn Python than to actually accomplish any end. The questions are roadblocks I run into along the way. No doubt there are better ways to do these things.

Comment: Your structure is quite iterative, would you consider changing it rather than going for multiprocessing? Or are you trying to learn multiprocessing?

Comment: Whatever I do, it's going to have to cycle through a lot of combinations, so I'm going to want to utilize multiprocessing (also I just want to know how to use it). But I'm open to changing the structure. I posted a question a few days ago about the optimization of that big nested loop. I can edit this one with relevant info if you want. I don't know if that would make this too off topic though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is essentially finding the cartesian product of the lists

[catcher_pool, first_pool, second_pool, third_pool, short_pool] + it.combinations(of_pool, 3)

Refer to this post to see how that can be done nicely:  [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists-in-python)

Then you can make a helper function to filter out invalid lineups

This should get you a reasonable speedup, but if you still want to parallelize, then I would take advantage of the tree-like structure of your code, and pick the first few players sequentially (giving you a list of tuples of the first few players), then map those tuples (in parallel) through the rest of your function.